# What do I do with the stunner on my wrist?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

I was given a wrist attachment that's supposed to be a stunner of some kind.  I was also told that when I come across a case when its needed I will be told, except I haven't come across that situation yet.  What am I supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do anything with it that I found except when they tell you to and even then it is not something you active but something that is used in cinematics.

From a mechanical point of view you as a **player** will never need it.

Comment: wow, that's incredibly lame